# How to pass json properties with values that represent number datatypes in react post method call

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I have a react app where I am making a post call to an api.  My post sends a key value object that is converted to json using JSON.stringify. This properties represent the fields in a database and values are numeric in some cases.  My problem is that I get a 400 error.

I suspect this is because the json object I am passing looks like this:

```
let data =
{
"field1": "value1",
"field2": "value2",
"count": "47"
}
```

I'm setting these property values from state like so:

```
let data =
{
"field1": state.value1,
"field2": state.value2,
"count": state.value3
}
```

However, `count` in my database table where the object is being posted to is a number field.

To test this theory, I created a hardcoded object that looks like the following and when I post that it works just fine:

```
let data =
{
"field1": "value1",
"field2": "value2",
"count": 47
}
```

Javascript is not typed so how can I create an object that looks like the one above where non string values are not enclosed in quotes?

Comment: The issue is that the value is a string, not an integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You can cast a `String` to `Integer` in Javascript in a number of ways.

#### Method 1:

```js
const stringAsNumber = "0";
const castedString = +stringAsNumber;
console.log(castedString); // 0
console.log(typeof castedString); // "number"
```

#### Method 2:

```js
const stringAsNumber = "0";
const castedString = parseInt(stringAsNumber);
console.log(castedString); // 0
console.log(typeof castedString); // "number"
```

#### So in your case, do the following:

```js
let data = {
    "field1": state.value1,
    "field2": state.value2,
    "count": +state.value3
}
```

Note: If you use `+` or `parseInt` on a string that cannot be a number then it will return `NaN`

Comment: Yes! Haven't worked with javascript in a while.  That's what I needed.